Are there any differences when calling an API with Blazor in different render modes?
I'm having problems calling my API from a Blazor app with Fluent UI (if that matters). When I start the app, in the OnInitializedAsync() method, I'm calling the API that should return a list of ids, and after that I'm calling my API again to get detailed information about specific id.
The problem is that, when I call the second API with a given id, the id parameter is not sent to the API. Any suggestions are welcome.
There are code snippets:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    FhirIgResponse res = await mappingService.GetBundles();
    bundleOptions = res.Results;
    selectedBundle = res.Results.First();
    await OnBundleSelect();
}

private async Task OnBundleSelect()
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedBundle))
        {
            execScript = await mappingService.GetExecScript(selectedBundle);
        }
        else
        {
            toastService.ShowError("Please select a valid Id");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        toastService.ShowError($"OnBundleSelect with parameter: {selectedBundle} and error: {ex.Message}.");
    }
}


private async Task<T> SendRequestAsync<T>(string url, HttpMethod method, object? parameters = null)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Parameter ${nameof(url)} is required.");
        }
        
        using (HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url))
        {
            if (method ==  HttpMethod.Post)
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Content = JsonContent.Create(parameters,
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"),
                    new JsonSerializerOptions() { DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull });
                await httpRequestMessage.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();
            }
            
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error sending request the status code was: {httpResponseMessage.StatusCode}. The response message was: {await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
            }

            string content = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Utilities.ParseContentToT<T>(content);
        }
}

I tried to change the render mode of Blazor, but without any results.

To answer your question, no the render mode doesn't matter. Where have you declared selectedBundle? These code snippets are not clear how they are related.

selectedBundle is declared in the razor view as a variable. When i get the information from the first call, i'm saving the value in it.

when you say you don't have an id does that mean that selectedBundle is the missing  id? What are you learning from stepping through your code?

When i debug my code i can see there is a value in selectedBundle, but it doesn't go down to the server

"it doesn't go down to the server" ... this is a little vague. What error are you getting? Where are you getting the error?

it doesn't go down to the server"  maybe we can use tools like fiddler to capture this request, and then try to call the API directly with tools like postman to make sure the call is successflly, then let's compare the content in fiddler to see the differences between the 2 requests.
